# Ruby to_bytes reverse function needed

Tags: ruby, string, byte

I have this function from github or whatever:

```
class String
  def to_bytes
    (0...self.length/2).map {|i|self[i*2,2].to_i(16)}
  end
end
```

and my point is, that I am not really sure what is the whole thing doing, especially the self[something] part and please can somebody help me to reverse this procedure? I am not experienced and  I kind of desperately need to get those numbers back into string.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I'll try to explain the method in as plain English as I can. `(0...self.length/2)` returns a number that is half the string's length. (`self` is a keyword that means, in the context of a method like `to_bytes`, the string upon which `to_bytes` is being requested.) `map` takes the number (half the string's length), takes two characters from the string at a time, and converts each pair to hex, and places the result in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can reliably convert the result of `to_bytes` back to the original string. Both `"a".to_bytes` and `"b".to_bytes` will produce `[0]`. However, assuming that this isn't a problem for you, the reverse of your `to_bytes` method would be something like this:

```
def reverse_string_to_bytes bytes
  result = ""
  bytes.each do |pair|
    result << pair.to_s(16)
  end
end
```

Comment: I see, this things does pretty much nothing at all, but when I look at the "a".to_bytes and some other examples, the to_bytes ruins the whole input... still wondering why would somebody do that, cause I am modifying code of someone else, but thanks for your time, I appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like much to do about nothing...

Why don't you just

```
"My string".bytes.reverse
# Or
def reverse_bytes(str)
    str.bytes.reverse
end
```